# Mongodb Agregation + Lookup

Tags: mongodb

Boa noite, preciso relacionar duas coleções no mongodb, são elas:

db.mercados 
db.produtos

```
db.mercados.find()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5bb90160995e46f1fdbf1fe8"),
  "nome_mercado": "teste",
  "localidade": "são paulo",
  "pagamentos": [
    "credito",
    "débito",
    "dinheiro",
    "vr",
    "va"
  ],
  "produtos": [
    {
      "ean": "9876",
      "preco": "2,00"
    },
    {
      "ean": "123",
      "preco": "1,99"
    }
  ],
  "data_de_atualizacao": "Sat Oct 06 2018 15:39:24 GMT-0300"
}


db.produtos.find()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5bb78c13ec8dee50a692d18f"),
  "ean": "123",
  "nome_produto": "Corona",
  "Categoria": "Cerveja"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5bb78c5fec8dee50a692d190"),
  "ean": "9876",
  "nome_produto": "passa tempo",
  "Categoria": "Bolacha"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5bb78f57844b17c8cadd039c"),
  "ean": "9876",
  "nome_produto": "traquinas",
  "Categoria": "Bolacha"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5bb78f9b844b17c8cadd039d"),
  "ean": "98765",
  "nome_produto": "cramecrack",
  "Categoria": "Bolacha"
}
```

Preciso de algo mais ou menos assim:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5bb90160995e46f1fdbf1fe8"),
  "nome_mercado": "teste",
  "localidade": "são paulo",
  "pagamentos": [
    "credito",
    "débito",
    "dinheiro",
    "vr",
    "va"
  ],
  "produtos": [
    {
      "ean": "9876",
      "preco": "2,00"
      "nome_produto": "traquinas",
      "Categoria": "Bolacha"
    },
    {
      "ean": "123",
      "preco": "1,99"
      "nome_produto": "Corona",
      "Categoria": "Cerveja"

    }
  ],
  "data_de_atualizacao": "Sat Oct 06 2018 15:39:24 GMT-0300"
}
```

Preciso relacionar as duas coleções, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo,

Diferente do paradigma do SQL, onde você relaciona tabelas e cruza dados na query, no MongoDB (NoSQL) você não vai relacionar as listas.

Você tem duas possibilidades aqui:

1. Buscar o mercado desejado na coleção 'mercados', e pegar os IDs (EANs) dos produtos para então buscar cada produto para obter as informações adicionais de que precisa na aplicação ou,
2. Criar redundância dos dados do produto na lista 'mercado.produtos' da sua coleção de 'mercados', de forma a já dispor de todos os dados necessários na consulta do mercado.

A segunda opção certamente vai escalar melhor, é mais adequada para bancos de dados NoSQL.

Em bancos não relacionais como o MongoDB, preocupe-se em estruturar os dados na hora da gravação nas coleções, criando as redundâncias necessárias, de forma que na consulta o dado já estará pronto para uso direto.

Answer (score 0):

Como Eduardo Klein escreveu " 'mercados', e pegar os IDs (EANs) dos produtos"
Espero que ajude.

```
db.mercados.aggregate([
 { $unwind: { 'path': '$produtos', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true }},
 {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'produtos',
            let: { prodean: '$produtos.ean', p:'$produtos.preco' },
            pipeline: [

                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: ['$ean', '$$prodean' ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project:{
                        preco:'$$p',
                        "ean" : 1,
                        "nome_produto" : 1,
                        "Categoria" : 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: 'produtos'
        }
    },
    { $unwind: { 'path': '$produtos', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true }},
    {
        $group:{
            _id: '$_id',
            nome_mercado:{$first: '$nome_mercado'},
            localidade:{$first: '$localidade'},
            pagamentos:{$first: '$pagamentos'},
            produtos:{$addToSet: '$produtos'},
            data_de_atualizacao:{$first: '$data_de_atualizacao'}
        }
    }
])
```